# Acrobat DC and acroforms / acrofields

Tags: adobe, acrobat, xfa, acrofields

we have been happily processing acroforms with our backend software. Now a customer provided forms created with latest Acrobat DC version. These forms cannot be processed by us, we do not understand the fields.

Is there any change apparent here? I tried to find something substantial on the Adobe website, but there is most of the time only "filling forms" and signing, not what technique is used for the forms.

If the customer uses latest acrobat to design forms, will these be acroforms or XFA technology or something completely different?

If these are not acroforms, can latest Adobe DC actually create acroforms? We tried to find it in the settings, but didn't find it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of any changes concerning the forms in Acrobat DC.

There is a chance for XFA, but you can check that quickly by opening the file in Acrobat/Reader and display the Document Properties, and look at the Creating Software entry. The tool creating XFA, LiveCycle Designer, is no longer bundled with Acrobat, therefore, the chance for XFA is slimmer.

Could it be that the files you get are digitally signed?

And, yes, Acrobat DC can/does create Acroform PDFs.